# How to refer to a cell using a string in VBScript?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to write a VBscript that will take three argument:
argument0 :  the excel file to modify, for example C:\temp\temp.xls

argument1:  the name of a text file containing the list of images to insert . 
The first three lines could be:
"c:\temp\image1.gif" 
"c:\temp\image2.gif"
"c:\temp\image3.gif"

argument2:  the name of a text file containing the list of the in which to insert the images. The first three lines could be:
"A2"
"C3"
"E2"

---

Here is what I have so far, my code crashes at this line: 
 mycell = xlObj.ActiveSheet.range(cellule)

---

```
argument0 = "C:\temp\temp.xls"
argument1 = "c:\temp\images.txt"
argument2= "c:\temp\cellules.txt"

Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Set file = fso.GetFile(WScript.Arguments(0)) 
Set file          = fso.GetFile(argument0) 
set file_images   =fso.OpenTextFile(argument1)
set file_cellules =fso.OpenTextFile(argument2)
set xlWB = xlObj.Workbooks.Open(file)



Do Until file_cellules.AtEndOfStream
 cellule   =     file_cellules.ReadLine
 image     =     file_images.ReadLine

 mycell = xlObj.ActiveSheet.range(cellule)
cellleft = mycell.Left
celltop = mycell.Top
cellheight =mycell.Height
cellwidth = mycellWidth

  With xlObj.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(image, _
    True, True, cellleft, celltop, cellwidth, cellheight)    
  End With
Loop        
  xlWB.save
  xlWB.close

xlObj.quit
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for replying but I get the same error.  Again, this is run as a VBscript if it helps. (unknown runtime error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the code was fine.  It's my input files that were wrong.
Removing the double quotes at the start and end of the lines fixed it.